# Method that run only with breakpoint

Tags: c#

//Edit

My application has a defined simple if statement.

```
while (true)
        {
            for (Int32 x = 0; x < 255; x++)
            {
                int state = GetAsyncKeyState(x);
                shift = buttons.ShiftKey;

                if (buttons.CapsLock)
                {
                    if (myLock == true)
                    {
                        myLock = false; break;
                    }

                    myLock = true;
                }
                else if (state == 1 || state == -32767)
                {
                    //something...
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is that it will not go into this method until I set the breakpoint. With him, the application works as it should.

buttons.CapsLock returns bool like below:

```
public bool CapsLock
{
    get { return Convert.ToBoolean(GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.CapsLock) & 0x8000); }
}
```

Comment: what method is this, how is it called? Remember - we absolutely nothing about your app. Only what you typed into the question

Comment: Simple void. The code above runs in while(true) loop.

Comment: How are you sure that it never goes in here without a breakpoint? Have you put some console/debug console output or something?

Comment: `while (true) { if (CapsLock) { Console.WriteLine("CapsLock true"); } }` prints the message for me a bunch without a break point from one capslock keypress. (moved CapsLock where my Main method is instead of `buttons`)

Comment: @BrootsWaymb Yes. I see the output on the console. Actually, what it does is it raises letters to uppercase. With breakpoint it will assign true to bool as I mentioned.

Comment: I am sure you are well aware that the method `GetAsyncKeyState` calls itself with `int state = GetAsyncKeyState(x);` and it may cause never ending recursive code execution.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging, do you understand the difference between "Step over" (F10) and "Step into" (F11)? I suspect that you are doing "Step over", and you need to be doing "Step into".

Since you are stepping over, it looks like it isn't going in there unless you have a breakpoint set; but trust me, it will have been going in there.

Comment: @maccettura [deleted] Yes, I believe that's what the OP is meaning, when he says "it will not go into this method until I set the breakpoint"; but we'll see if he marks this as the answer...

Comment: I think it is if this is genuinely what the OP is confused about, but I'm not sure if we can definitely say it is what he is confused about.

Comment: Well... Simple debugging with writeline has revealed the truth. Somehow when i press CapsLock it will be assign to true and then to false again. I have a bug somewhere but I'll find it now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @LuckyMan1234 This may be nothing to do with anything; but I wanted to be sure that you know that the "break" will only take you out of the "for", not out of the "while", which might be causing the bug you're describing.